# Opposite to FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS

Tags: java, android

I have made  a transparent status bar with

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

How do i get back to default state.?

Comment: Use [clearFlags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#clearFlags(int))

Comment: @dSanders thanks alot, here's the full answer 
`getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

Answer (score 2):

You can unset the flags by using `clearFlags()` as following :

**KOTLIN**

```kotlin
var win:Window = requireActivity().window
win.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

**JAVA**

```java
getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```